# Using multiple type injections in service creating

Tags: symfony

I have a service that needs two injections, one by a method call and one by construct call:

```
class EventRepository extends EntityRepository implements IEventRepository
{
    private $interestRepository;

    public function __construct(IInterestRepository $interestRepository)
    {
        $this->interestRepository = $interestRepository;
    }
}
```

my service.yml is this:

```
  site.event_repository:
     class: CMS\EventBundle\Bundle\Repository\EventRepository
     factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", getRepository]
     arguments:
       [CMS\EventBundle\Entity\Event]
```

How can I inject a parameter in construct?

Comment: When using a factory to create the service, you cannot control what is passed to the constructor of your created service (passing arguments is the job of the factory method). You can only control what arguments are passed to the factory method.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do this, I would recommend you to create a class factory and inject both arguments and the entity manager on it so then you can have your class. Other option is maybe using compiler pass and make it manual.

Answer (score 1):

You may inject any amount of services/parameters passing them to `arguments` or `calls`:

```
some_service:
    class: Here\Is\MyService
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@any.other.service"]
    calls:
        - [ setEnvironment, [ %kernel.environment% ] ]
        - [ setSomething,   [ "@some.thing" ] ]
```